# Xtemplate shows blank item instead of not showing it with sencha touch 2.1

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

What i want to do is to show the item of a list of data conditionally,that is , when the item meet the condition,it will show,otherwise,it will not show(not means show a blank item).
My data to be showed is like this :

```
 [
      {'label':'one','isvisible':'1','value':'one'},
      {'label':'two','isvisible':'1','value':''},
      {'label':'three','isvisible':'0','value':'three'},
      {'label':'four','isvisible':'0','value':''}
 ]
```

And my list is like below:

```
                        xtype : 'list',
                        id :  'myListId',
                        disableSelection : true,
                        itemTpl : [
                                 '<tpl if="isvisible == 1 && value !=\'\'  ">',
                                    '{label}{value}',
                                 '</tpl>'
                        ]
```

But when the list showed,i have got some blank rows if the item meets the condition(the property 'visible' is 1 or the property 'value' is empty).

At first,i used `'<tpl for="." '` ,I followed this link:  [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190743-Using-Xtemplate-showing-blank-rows) but my list of data have no root node,so i used the itemtpl above.

I do not want to modify the strcuture of my list of data,so how can i do ?

**UPDATE**:
 I do not use a store.I just get the data then assign the data to the data config of the list like:

```
var data=[{text:'1'},{text:'2'},{text:'3'}];//usually the data array comes from the response of an ajax request to the remote server.
var list=Ext.getCmp('myListId');
list.setData(data);
```

Comment: The property in your data is called `isvisible`, you're checking the condition `visible`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli sorry for that. I have edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can filter the store in your controller, before pushing the list view:

```
store.filter('isvisible', '1');
```

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

EDIT:

```
initialize: function(list) {
    var data = [];

    Ext.each(list.getData(), function(rec) {
        if (rec.data.isvisible == 1) data.push(rec);
    });

    list.setData(data);
}
```

Comment: Many thans for reply.But i do not use a store. I just use the method 'setData' of the list

Comment: @gabrielaflext I've edited this code with a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
          {
                xtype : 'list',
                disableSelection : true,
                itemTpl : [
                     '<tpl if="isvisible == 1 && value !=\'\'  ">',
                     '{label}{value}',
                      '</tpl>'
                ],
               listeners : {
                initialize: function(list, eOpts ) {
                    var visibleFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
                        property: 'isvisible',
                        value   : 1
                    });

                    var valueFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
                        filterFn: function(item) {                               
                            return item.data.value.length != 0;
                        }
                    });

                    list.getStore().setFilters([visibleFilter,valueFilter]);
                }
            }
        }
```